# How to show  a default selecteditem in a flex combobox

Tags: apache-flex, list, combobox

In a flex application how to display default selecteditem from the dataprovider of the combobox.

I'm using {staticdataholder.currencylist}.

For example: I have to show `INDIA` so it should be selected as default from the list.

Where `INDIA` is one of the value in the currencylist.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through your dataProvider and set the selected object:

Example:

```
for each ( var obj:Object in staticdataholder.currencylist ) {
    if ( obj == "INDIA" ) {
        cbx.selectedItem = obj;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `cbx.selectedItem = "INDIA"`?

Comment: @alxx, `INDIA` could just be a value of a property in the `currencylist`'s object. If it were a list of just strings your example could work though.

Comment: AFAIK, if you can test object with equality, you can set selectedItem directly, list will find it itself.

Comment: If you can test object with equality, yes you can set selectedItem directly.

Answer (score -1):

Hi guys i have found another solution for this..kindly checkout the same and its suits well like the above one..

create an ASUTil file where you have get convertmap and get value method
 keep th countrylist in static dataHolder....
currencycmb is the ID for the combobox....

then....keep the following in init method();

```
currencyCmb.selectedItem = ASUtil.getValue(StaticDataHolder.countryList,"SGD");
```

Hope This is great to Feed....:-)